# Extend using defineProperty, where put the private variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following factory in which I extended Timesheet with a new property: start.  However I'm somehow not doing it correctly because _start seems to be at the wrong level.  All Timesheet entries are returning the same start.

How can I put it within Timesheet ?

```
.factory('Timesheets', function($resource, LinkData) {
  var Timesheet = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/timesheets/:id',{id:'@id'}, {update:{method:'PUT'}});

  var _start;

  Object.defineProperty(Timesheet.prototype, 'start', {
    get: function() {
      if (_start == undefined){
        _start = moment(this.time_start).format();
      }
      return _start;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      if (moment(value).isValid()) {
        this.time_start = value;
        _start = value;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: what is returned in factory? as service is singleton, you probably need to put `_start` in `Timesheet` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular service is designed to be singleton, so there is always one `_start`.

what you want is probably to put the `_start` in `Timesheet` object.

```
module.factory('Timesheets', function($resource, LinkData) {
    var Timesheet = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/timesheets/:id',{id:'@id'}, {update:{method:'PUT'}});

    return {
        getTimesheetObj: getTimesheetObj
    }

    function getTimesheetObj() {

        var timesheet = new Timesheet();
        timesheet._start = undefined;

        Object.defineProperty(timesheet, 'start', {
            get: function() {
                if (this._start === undefined){
                    this._start = moment(this.time_start).format();
                }
                return this._start;
            },
            set: function(value) {
                if (moment(value).isValid()) {
                this.time_start = value;
                this._start = value;
            }
        };

        return timesheet;
    }

});
```